# Apache 2.4 + XSendfile appends charset=utf-8 to content-type header

Tags: apache, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, x-sendfile

We just migrated one of our web applications (classic lamp stack) from Ubuntu 14/Apache 2.2/PHP 5.5 to Ubuntu 16/Apache 2.4/PHP 7.0. Everything worked pretty smooth. There is only one part that is giving me headaches at the moment:

One route in our application checks the incoming file request and delivers that file via XSendfile (third party contents). The content-type for the file delivery is set explicit by the application. This means, for example, we append a content-type of `text/html` for `*.html` files. This worked really smooth and the browser received that exact content type.

Now, on the new machine (same code and same files to deliver), the content-type received by the browser is `text/html;charset=utf-8`. There are some charset metadata appended to the content-type.

This is pretty bad for us, because there are some files containing `iso-8859-1` encoded contents. The result are encoding errors in the displayed html file.

I have triple checked everything. The content-type we are placing in the HTTP headers are explicitly set **without** the utf-8 charset metadata.

Right now I am checking various Apache2/XSendfile specific configurations for any hints about that behaviour.

Has anybody else experienced similar behaviour on Apache 2.4 using XSendfile? Is it right, that the content-type sent by Apache has a higher importance than the one in the html meta tag? How can I disable automatic appending of charset meta infos in the content-type header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem causing havok on an Android app expecting the `text/html` MIME verbatim, and found out it is actually a PHP config changed in an update. In PHP 5.6, they changed the default `default_charset` setting from `""` to `"UTF-8"`.

You can either change this in your appropriate `php.ini`, or simply add a monkey-patch `ini_set('default_charset', NULL);` *before* your `header()` calls.

> default_charset string
>
> In PHP 5.6 onwards, "UTF-8" is the default value and its value is used as the default character encoding for htmlentities(), html_entity_decode() and htmlspecialchars() if the encoding parameter is omitted...
>
> All versions of PHP will use this value as the charset within the default Content-Type header sent by PHP if the header isn't overridden by a call to header().

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset